# Свойство CSS display:flex ведет себя неадекватно

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте, кто знает в чем может быть проблема?
Поставил `display:flex;`, но он себя ведет неадекватно: никаких отступов нет, длина в порядке, но какой-то невидимый отступ появляется сверху, при смене расположения со start на end отступ перемещается то вверх то вниз.

```css
.my-flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}

.tourdiv {
  display:flex;
  background:red;
  width:69%;
  margin:0 2% 0 0;
  min-height:20%;
  max-height:20%;
}

.gallery {
  display:flex;
  background:red;
  width:28%;
  margin:0 1% 0 0;
  min-height:20%;
  max-height:20%;

}
```

```html
<div class="my-flex-container">
  <div class="tourdiv">
    <span class="galtext">Internal Tours</span>     
  </div>         
  <div class="gallery">
    <span class="galtext">Rent a Car</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Скрин 1]

[image: Скрин 2]

Comment: А разметку можно увидеть со стилями?

Comment: поправил, знаю что - то то не дописал , но разобраться в масштабировании flex не могу ,

Comment: И ещё вопрос: чего конкретно хотите добиться с помощью flex?

Comment: он хорошо растягивает и делает элементы резиновыми , да и float не приходится использовать как при display:block;

Comment: Это понятно, но что конкретно хотите добиться используя на данных элементах flex? Растянуть на всю высоту родительного блока? Или что?

Comment: нет , видите пустые отступы сверху?
Я хочу уменьшить эти отступы и все, чтобы пустое место не оставалось
В display block делается через margin , но тут margin не задан , берется высота родителя , а как уменьшить высоту родителя я не могу понять

Comment: Исправьте свойство `height:200px;` в `.my-flex-container`. Или удалите это свойство, тогда контейнер родительский будет высоте контента дочерних элементов.

Comment: Решил , решение оказалось глупым как и вопрос с моей стороны изза не внимательности , добавляем к родителю height:50px;
и меняется высота.

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

[Вот инструкция Flexbox](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.my-flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #f99;
}

.tourdiv {
  display: block;
  background:red;
  width:70%;
  min-height:20%;
  max-height:20%;
}

.gallery {
  display: block;
  background:red;
  width:30%;
  min-height:20%;
  max-height:20%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-flex-container">
  <div class="tourdiv">
<span class="galtext">Internal Tours</span>
  </div>    
  
  <div class="gallery">
<span class="galtext">Rent a Car</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Автору нужно было уменьшить высоту самого блока `.my-flex-container`, о чём он написал в комментарии выше

Comment: @Инженер-погромист Ну тогда ладно. Не защитается мне в карму:)

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox**, это концепция, предназначенная для гибкой вёрстки с минимальным конфигурированием. У вас же перебор параметрами габаритов:

```
  width:69%;
  margin:0 2% 0 0;
  min-height:20%;
  max-height:20%;
```

И ещё всё в процентах. `width` - например заменяется на `flex-grow`, и/или `flex-basis`. `margin` - следовало бы убрать у нодов вовсе, иначе не будет красивых квадратных отступов. `min-height` и `max-height` в одно значение - дело хозяйское, но флекс более подразумевает гибкость, нежели жёсткое ограничение.

Ну и по теме вопроса:

> но какой-то невидимый отступ появляется сверху

Поменяйте `align-items` в значение `flex-start` или `stretch` . А вообще для понимания флекса советую сохранить страницу: https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/yNNZxr , чтобы играться с флексом по клику на рабочем столе, я бы ещё апгрейдил код и добавил параметры `max-width`, `max-height` , и `margin` для дочерних нодов.

Comment: Оу, посмотрел на дату вопроса...

Answer (score -4):

Сделайте резет для начала `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` отступы уйдут.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Исполняя код который приведен в вопросе, получаются отступы от края окна броузера, думал вопрос именно об этих отступах.